# gtk.treeviewcolumn not sorting

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

I've gotten a sortable treeview working. Clicking on the columns makes it sort by ascending order, and clicking it again makes it sort by descending order. However, if I click on the column header a third time, it goes to some "unsorted" state, instead of back to ascending. I connected a function to the `clicked` signal of the column, and printed out the column's `get_sort_order()`, and for each click I get `SORT_ASCENDING` for ascending, `SORT_DESCENDING` for descending, and `SORT_DESCENDING` again for the "unsorted" state. My tree view construction is something like this:

```
    self.hsModel = gtk.TreeStore(*[c[0] for c in columns])
    self.hsModelFilter = self.hsModel.filter_new()
    self.hsModelSort = gtk.TreeModelSort(self.hsModelFilter)
    #... define filterfunc ...
    self.hsModelFilter.set_visible_func(filterfunc)
    self.hsSelect = gtk.TreeView(self.hsModelSort)

    cl = gtk.TreeViewColumn(ctitle, renderer, **attrcols)                    
    cl.set_clickable(True)
    cl.set_sort_column_id(COL_ACTUALTIME)

    #... define sortdate ...
    self.hsModelSort.set_sort_func(COL_ACTUALTIME, sortdate)
    self.hsModelSort.set_sort_column_id(COL_ACTUALTIME, gtk.SORT_DESCENDING)
```

I *never* want to be in this "unsorted" state. I want it to either sort by ascending order or descending order. How do I get rid of the "unsorted" state?

Answer (score 1):

The `self.hsModelSort.set_default_sort_func(None)` works, but you will lose the original state (previous any sort), if  is that what you want then thats the solution, if you want to keep the original form you must set the default function to some function that sort the column to the original state.

Most likely you already sort the values in descending order in the first place so you just need to do:

> self.hsModelSort.set_sort_column_id(COL_ACTUALTIME, gtk.SORT_ASCENDING)
>       self.hsModelSort.set_default_sort_func(None)

I hope this clarify my point:

```
import gtk

w = gtk.Window()
w.resize(300, 300)

cols = [(1,8,3),
        (7,12,9),
        (4,5,6),
        (10,11,12)]

model = gtk.ListStore(int, int, int)
model.set_sort_column_id(0, gtk.SORT_ASCENDING)
model.set_default_sort_func(None )

#sort columns in ascending order for the column 0
cols.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(x[0],y[0]), reverse=True)

for c in cols:
    model.append(c)

tv = gtk.TreeView(model)
tv.set_headers_clickable(True)

columns = ('one', 'two', 'three')
renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
for i, c in enumerate(columns):
    col = gtk.TreeViewColumn(c, renderer)
    col.add_attribute(renderer, 'text', i)
    col.set_clickable(True)
    col.set_sort_column_id(0)
    col.set_sort_indicator(True)
    tv.append_column(col)

w.add(tv)
w.show_all()
w.connect('destroy', lambda _: gtk.main_quit())
gtk.main()
```

Comment: you both misunderstood me. i already get the original state, and i don't want it (why would I?). updated question to be clearer.

Comment: Run the example, is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test, but try if

```
self.hsModelSort.set_default_sort_func (None)
```

helps.  Default value is just "use underlying order", but should be possible to reset to "no sort function at all" state.